# Reliably detach from a Raspberry Pi rsync process and leave it running

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, rsync, openssh

For years I've been using the following sequence (via **ssh** from my Linux Mint PC) on several different "headless" Raspberry Pi's to copy large folders over the Internet to my friend's PC (also Mint, and we're both on the same **Zerotier** network).

> sudo rsync  --bwlimit=300   -avP --append-verify "src_folder" "user2@nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:/dst_folder"
> (Ctrl/Z)
> bg
> disown
> exit

...after which I can just leave the Pi to chug away for hours, if necessary. But it was always difficult for my non-technically-minded friend to establish whether and when any given copy had successfully completed, so with some help from chatgpt, I ended up with this **bash** script (parameters 1=source, 2=dest)...

> #!/bin/bash
> folder_path="$1"
> size_file="${folder_path%/}.size"
> dest="$2"
> find "$folder_path" -type f -exec du -b {} + | sort -n | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1}' > "$size_file"
> sudo rsync  --bwlimit=300   -avP --append-verify "$size_file"  "$dest"
> sudo rsync  --bwlimit=300   -avP --append-verify "$folder_path"  "$dest"

The basic idea is I create a text file<sup>1</sup> with the same name as the source folder *plus extension **.size***, which I send *before* the main folder. The ***.size*** file simply contains the exact size in bytes of the largest file in the source folder. I wrote a little utility program for my friend (**user2**) to use via **Open with...** in Nemo File Manager - all that does is compare the size of the largest *received* file with the value in the ***.size*** file, and display an appropriate status window using **Zenity** (size *still increasing*, copy *complete*, or copy *stalled*).

My problem is that although everything runs fine so long as I keep the ssh link open between Pi and PC, when I do **Ctrl/Z ... bg  [... disown ... exit**] with the *script* (rather than the original *single **rsync** command*), sometimes **rsync** continues, other times it stops (stalled or terminated, I don't know).

I've tried various ways of detaching from the Pi (repeating the **bg** command, including **fg**, running the script thru **sudo**, simply closing the **ssn** connection window without running **disown** or **exit**,...). But nothing seems to work *consistently*, the way it did before I started trying to use a script.

---

<sup>1</sup> I couldn't possibly have written that **find ... awk...** command myself (it was entirely chatgpt), so don't assume I have significant command-line skills. But I don't think that's relevant to my problem.

Comment: Why not just use _screen_ or _tmux_?

Comment: Because I don't know how (but I expect chatgpt could help on that front). Are you suggesting that the problem would go away if I used one of them? Which is easiest?

Comment: Found this which may be relevant: [Using TMUX on PI](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/run-long-running-scripts-raspberry-pi) : I don't know that screen runs on the RaspberryPI, but I assume it does.... `screen -S letrun` then usually it's `CTL+A, D` to disconnect and `screen -X letrun` to reconnect/reattach. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Xinthral: Thanks. I'll give that a go. I never really need to "reattach" to the copy process (which I assume disappears elegantly, safely, and completely if & when it finishes copying the entire source folder). But being able to do that might be useful in some other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like to understand why my bash script doesn't always work the same as just entering the three relevant commands consecutively on the command line, but following @Xinthral's suggestion, I [installed tmux](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/run-long-running-scripts-raspberry-pi) and ran...

> tmux new -s my_rsync_session
> **rsync_size.sh** "src_folder" "user2@N.N.N.N:/dst_folder"
> Ctrl + **b**
> **d**

(Detaches from tmux job, after which I just **exit** from the Pi command line **ssh** connection.)

So far, so good.